# The difference between "throw" keyword and the usage of code written between "catch" curly brackets

Tags: c#

1. Generally, when can we use the " throw " keyword?
2. I cannot differentiate between the usage of code written between  "catch" curly brackets and the usage of "throw".

Can anyone explain to me using the following example?

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{ 
    class RethrowDemo
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying in main() method");
                MethodA();
            }
            catch(Exception ae)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("caught in main() method-- \n{0}",ae.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Main() method is done");
        }

        private static void MethodA()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying in Method A");
                MethodB();
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught in method A");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void MethodB()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying in Method B");
                MethodC();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught in method B");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void MethodC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Method C");
            throw (new Exception("This came from method C"));    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. When you want to throw an exception... 2. It's catching an exception, and then rethrowing the exception.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I believe that throw will also retain the original exception's stack trace, whilst if you decide to use the throw new keyword then you lose the previous stack trace

Comment: @SomeStudent: When you rethrow an exception as the OP does here with the "naked' `throw` statement, the original call stack is retained. It's only if you throw a new exception that the call stack is lost, but for that scenario there's a constructor for the new exception that allows the old exception to be passed in, thus retaining the context.

Comment: Some pages that might be helpful: [throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw), [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

Comment: https://berserkerdotnet.github.io/blog/rethrow-exception-correctly-in-dotnet/

Comment: How are there `4` upvotes for a question that can be answered by reading the documentation for the keyword being asked about? Seems more like a candidate for a downvote due to "lack of reasearch effort" (no offense to the OP, just curious)

Answer (score 1):

The throw keyword is used when you want to throw an exception manually. [Check this for details.](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/throw-csharp) You use the try-catch block when you are usually working with files or connecting to a host, etc. When your code can run into an exception like file does not exist or similar and you put the code inside the catch {} which will be executed if an exception is thrown. [Check this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

I will add my answer here similar to what I wrote in the comment section, thank you to 500 - Internal Server Error (great username btw) for extra context.

The `throw` by itself keyword will retain the exception that was thrown before it, thus you retain the original stack trace. Using `throw new` will create a new exception which will get rid of the old stack trace unless you use the constructor that 500 mentioned.

As Zoltan mentioned, the usage of a try-catch block is used in situation such as file reading, connections, api calls, etc. where the catch block is there to prevent a hard system crash and allows you to do some work as well. Perhaps you want to propogate the error (thus the throw keyword) or you just want to swallow it and log it somewhere else.

That is, as far as I am aware so far, the biggest difference between `throw` and `throw new`

Comment: You can do `throw new RuntimeException("My error", ex);` where `ex` is the exception caught in the `catch`. If I remember correctly that will preserve the stack trace while adding your exception to it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try{
            method2();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
    
    static void method1(){
        throw new InvalidProgramException("Exception 1");
    }
    
    static void method2(){
        try{
            method1();
        }catch(InvalidProgramException e){
            Console.WriteLine("I am method2. I am bad");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to throw an exception manually, then you can use the `throw` keyword. Consider the `method1`. In `method1` I have thrown an `InvlidProgramException`.

Now consider the `method2`. If we use only `throw` keyword then we call that `rethrow`. It will throw the error caught by the `catch` block.

If the catch block caught any exception, the code inside the `catch` block will be executed. In `method2` when it catches the exception, first print `I am method2. I am bad` and then throw the error caught by `catch`, in this case, `InvalidProgramException`.

Since I have used `Exception` in the main method `catch` block, it can catch any type of exception. Otherwise `catch` can catch only the specified type of exception, like `method2` catch block, can catch only `InvalidProgramException`.